# In what order should a newcomer watch the Pokémon series?

Tags: suggested-order, pokemon

I am planning on watching the *Pokémon* series but I would like to know what is the correct order to watch the series.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-correct-order-of-Pokemon-seasons-until-now

Comment: Usually, for everything the correct order to watch something is the chronological way. Start with the oldest and watch it by looking at premiere dates.

Comment: Whilst "chronologically" is a good answer, the real issue here is at what point to watch the movies - where do they slot into the narrative of the TV series? Between which episodes? There is also the question of spin off media, such as Pokémon Origins and Pokémon Generations. A good answer would probably also mention episodes which were cut from various releases, and when to watch them (e.g. without tracking down "The Legend of Dratini" episode, never aired in English, later episodes where Ash owns a herd of Tauros make no sense).